# Windows software to help focus when spacing out

Tags: windows, productivity

I have a lot of trouble staying on task sometimes, even if that task is playing a game. But I don't like timers or forcibly blocking sites/software as I would rather want to try and break the spacing out before it goes on for long and blocking things won't stop it.

Was thinking it be in the form of check-ins, would rather it be Windows-based. My ideal was a combination of tracking app/site and mouse usage. Having triggers, like using -blank- site for 1 hour straight, or the mouse not been moved in x amount of time. This would trigger a diaglog box to check-in, to keep track of what is distracting. And help suggest an alternative thing to do.

Most of what I've found are just timed reminders, timers, to do lists. Which don't really help as timers could help half the time, the other time it would just interrupt. Not sure if anything close to it exists, appreciate the reads and replies :)